# Why does PyMongo give Unsupported projection option: $substr when listing collections?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following code:

```
client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client['my_db']
print(db.collection_names())
#print(db.list_collection_names())
```

and I get the error

> File "C:\Users\gwerner004\eclipse-workspace\MongoTestRasa\FirstTest.py", line 17, in connect
>       print(db.collection_names())
>     File "C:\Users\gwerner004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 715, in collection_names
>       nameOnly=True, **kws)]
>     File "C:\Users\gwerner004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 677, in list_collections
>       **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\gwerner004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 651, in _list_collections
>       cursor = self._command(sock_info, cmd, slave_okay)["cursor"]
>     File "C:\Users\gwerner004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 514, in _command
>       client=self.__client)
>     File "C:\Users\gwerner004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 579, in command
>       unacknowledged=unacknowledged)
>     File "C:\Users\gwerner004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 150, in command
>       parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
>     File "C:\Users\gwerner004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
>       raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
>   pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unsupported projection option: $substr

Why do I get a failure for such a basic operation?  I am running on Windows 10 and using Python 3.6.7.  My PyMongo is 3.7.2

Comment: I have the same problem with `list_collections` as well, but I use CosmoDB instance

Comment: I've found that `client['my-collection'].list_collection_names('%d')` will give another error saying: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'`

Answer (score 0):

The $substr operator works on all currently supported MongoDB versions (2.6-4.4):

```
> db.foo.aggregate([{$project:{"name": {"$substr": ["$name", 2, -1]}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc032e56bc5b2e2216cdd08"), "name" : "llo" }
```

Most likely you are using either an ancient MongoDB installation or, per one of the comments, an imitation database like CosmosDB that does not behave as MongoDB itself would (which are also not supported by official MongoDB drivers).